# If f: H→G is an injection and E⊆H, prove that f^(-1)(f(E))=E

Tags: real-analysis

I got a problem in doing

$$
If \ \ f:\ H → G \ \ is \ \ injective \ \ and\ \  E⊆H, \ \ prove \ \ that\ \ f^{-1}(f(E))=E
$$

What I have done is $$Let \ \ x\in f^{-1}(f(E)),\ \ then \ \ we\ \ have\ \ f(x)\in f(E)$$

Does anyone could help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Continuing what you have, you need to show that $x\in E$. Now, $f(x)\in f(E)$ so $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $y\in E$. But $f$ is injective, so $y=x$ and you indeed have $x\in E$.

Conversely, if $x\in E$, then $f(x)\in f(E)$ which immediately gives $x\in f^{-1}(f(E))$. This direction does not require injectiveness.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much